# Register DeviceId with Unity Native Plugin

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, push

I'm using Unity Native Plugin library to implement GCM. When i try to get register device id i don't receive either fail or success response. i don't receive anything at all. my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="my_package_name" 
android:versionName="2.0" android:versionCode="2">
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

<permission android:name="my_package_name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="my_package_name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application>
  <receiver
    android:name="com.androidnative.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <category android:name="my_package_name" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service  android:name="com.androidnative.gcm.GcmIntentService"/>
<activity android:name="com.androidnative.billing.core.AN_BillingProxyActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
<activity android:name="com.androidnative.AndroidNativeProxy" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" />
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
<activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" />
<activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true" />
<activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Could you help me to setup it correctly? Is it connected with manifest?

Comment: Your manifest shouldn't really matter in this case. Are you referring to the [Android Native Plugin for Unity](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10825)? The docs for push notifications are [here](https://unionassets.com/android-native-plugin/push-notifications-169). You can check if your message was received with `GoogleCloudMessageService.instance.LoadLastMessage();
`.